# Ruby on rails scaffolding in Netbeans 6.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding, netbeans6.5

I am playing with the scaffold feature of rails in Netbeans 6.5. 
Right click->Generate gives me a menu that allows me to create the scaffold but asks for "attribute pairs". I have some tables with quite a few columns and would rather have the scaffolded pages include them all instead of specifying each one individually. Does anyone know how to do this within Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to scaffold the all the tables all at once? I think the script doesn't do that.

But you can indeed generate a table with all the required columns by specifying all the attribute pairs. I don't use Netbeans, sorry, but you could specify them on command line this way.

Each attribute pairs is a column in your table. For example, this command line

```
./script/generate scaffold blogpost title:string body:text
```

generates a controller, a model and some views with the name of blogpost. `blogpost` would be your tablename, and `title:string` is an attribute pair. For more attribute pair within the same table, just append them to the end, space delimited. Hopefully there's a menu you can do they same in Netbeans.

I hope this helps!

EDIT: Just saw a screenshot of the function in Netbeans. Under 'Model name' you can specify your table name. Under attribute pairs you can list all the columns in your table like shown above.

```
title:string body:text
```

If you are deciding to use Rails with tables that already exists, that's a more advanced topic because Rails impose a certain column names convention of it's own and it possibly means you are not going to comply with it.

[Rails with Non-Rails Database Design - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651436/rails-with-non-rails-database-design)

Comment: As it happens I am using an existing database. It seems to work fine with rails, in that the scaffolding is working and I can see that all of the data is being pulled out of it just fine. I am looking for a way to avoid typing in attribute pairs for all 20 columns of the table while staying within Netbeans (I'm trying to get a good workflow going with it). 
Thanks for helping!